# Docker-compose port range forward

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The documentation is really lacking here.

```
ports:
  - "20000-20100"
```

works fine for one port (just "20000" does not work tho. It seemingly binds to a random port above 40k somewhere), but I can't find a reliable way to forward a range of ports instead of just one.

```
- "20000-20100"
- "10000-10100:20000-20100"
- "20000-20100:20000-20100"
```

None of these works

I have also exposed 20000-30000 in the Dockerfile, but I'm under impression that this shouldn't really matter. Am I being stupid here? This seems like such an easy thing, but I've been hammering for hours now unable to get the connections working.

Edit:

Using - "20000-20010" exposes these ports:

0.0.0.0:43809->20000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43808->20001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43807->20002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43806->20003/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43805->20004/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43804->20005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43803->20006/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43802->20007/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43801->20008/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43800->20009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43799->20010/tcp

Using - "20000-20010:20000-20010" exposes these ports:

0.0.0.0:20000-20010->20000-20010/tcp

Which seems correct, but I'm unable to actually make any connections to them.

Edit2: Docker-compose

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  sshd:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "23:22"
      - "20000-20010:20000-20010"
    environment:
      REDIS_ADDRESS: redis
      DEBUG: 'sshd:*,ioredis:*'
  web:
    image: controller_web
    ports:
      - target: 3000
        published: 3000
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      REDIS_ADDRESS: redis
      DEBUG: 'sshd:*,ioredis:*'
  redis:
    image: "redis"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

# add openssh and clean
RUN apk add --update openssh \
&& rm  -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
    python \
    make \
    g++

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
COPY . /usr/src/app

#make sure we get fresh keys
RUN rm -rf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 20000-30000
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Can you post your compose file and the Dockerfile for this service? I've just tested this myself and it all works as expected. Also it looks like the documentation is fine - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports, it's just not working in your case :)

Comment: Please be specific about "doesn't work", how are you testing it? Is your app inside the container listening on all those ports, and binding to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Added the Dockerfile and compose. They also include some sshd stuff, which is what I'm using to test these ports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that the [docker-compose ports documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) does not provide sufficient info on the syntax for the range mapping of ports. To understand the syntax, check the [docker run documentation on ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

In particular,

```
- "20000-20100" means: Expose the container ports in the range 20000 to 20100 into random ports on the host machine
- "10000-10100:20000-20100" means: Expose the container ports in the range 20000 to 20100 into random ports on the host machine in the range of 10000 to 10100
- "20000-20100:20000-20100" similar to the above
```

In your case, all these should allow you to access the containerized application

Comment: Thanks, that is really nice to know, although something I've pretty much worked out on my own already. I am still baffled as to why it works with a single port but not a range.